# Help understanding rational proof given three rationals $x,y,z$ if $x = z$ and $y = z$ then $x =y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, rational-numbers

I'm having trouble grasping a specific step in the following proof:

given three rationals $x,y,z$  if $x = z$ and $y = z$ then $x =y $

so it starts with defining x y and z to be a rational.

with $ x = z$  and  $y = z $

so there exists integers a,b,c,d,e,f such that $x = \frac{a}{b}$ $y = \frac{c}{d}$ and $z = \frac{e}{f}$
( b d and f cannot be 0)

so thus we know that since $x = z$ and $y =z$  then $af = eb$ and $de = cf$ due to the equality of rationals.

now this last step is something I don't quite understand.
It says that by algebra, that we can  multiply $af$ and $de$, along with  $eb$ and $cf$  to make:

$afde = ebcf $

then we get $ad = bc$ which shows that $x = y$

How exactly is it valid to multiply af and de and eb and cf and equate each other? How is this a valid substitution?

Comment: If $r = s$ and $t = u$ then $(r \times t) = (s \times t)  = (s \times u).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rationals are those numbers which can be expressed in p/q form where p,q are coprime.
Let x = $\frac{a}{b}$ and y = $\frac{c}{d} $ and z = $\frac{e}{f}$.
Now if $x = z$ then $a*f=b*e$ and if $y=z$ then $d*e = c*f$
Now we are dealing with $a*f,b*e,d*e,c*f$ which are all some integers/whole numbers.
Now to prove that $x=y$ it is enough to prove that $ad=bc$
So lets now multiply the equation $ a*f = b*e$ with $d*e$ on both sides.
So $a*f*d*e = b*e*d*e $ But we know $d*e=c*f$.
So $a*f*d*e = b*e*c*f $
Now cancelling the common terms $f,e$ we get $ a*d=b*c$
Hence we proved the claim.

Comment: "We know $d*e = c*f$", but we also know $x=y$, and $y=z$. So putting the value of $y$ from the 1st equation into the second equation, $x=z$. As simple as that.

Comment: @DS Hi there, please read the question... The author clearly doesn't want to use if x=y,y=z then x=z directly and instead want to prove it.

Comment: "So $a*f*d*e = b*e*d*e$ but we know $d*e = c*f$ So $a*f*d*e = b*e*c*f$ " is just the same thing as having : "$p=q$ but we know $q=r$ so $p=r$".